# Gap between UITextField / UILabel and buttons below (Xcode storyboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

In Xcode in my storyboard I pinned the top element, which is a UITextField, to the top of the view controller. This worked fine, but when I try and pin the button below to the UITextField, there's still a gap when I run it in the simulator. Same thing when I use a UILabel.

How do I fix this?

[image: UITextField Gap]

Edit:

[image: Constraints]

Comment: Can you post pics of storyboard and the simulator to demonstrate? Might be easier to understand.

Comment: @Tim I updated my question to include a screenshot of both.

Comment: Have you set a height constraint on the text field?  I see some red colored constraints and that usually means something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your first button is NOT constrained to the text field, you can see this by the lack of an I-beam between them in storyboard. Add this constraint, and you should be good. Use the Pin menu (see image)

Also, you need to add constraints for Y (center)

[image]

UPDATE: Here is how you check all constraints at once:

[image]

And here is what a correctly linked button looks like:

[image]

Comment: I ctrl-dragged from the button to the text field and clicked vertical spacing. Is this not how to do it?

Comment: updated answer. The click-drag should have worked, but it obviously didn't take.

Comment: this works for the first button but when I do the same for the two below, the space between the text field and first button appears again.

Comment: Then you've got a conflicting constraint on one of them. Look in the Inspector on the right, click on the ruler icon at the top, and it lists all constraints for that view/button. You can also see constraints listed in the Document Outline of storyboard.

Comment: I checked the constraints in the ruler tab and all it has is the pin and an alignment constraint, and even if I don't add the alignment constraint it still has the gap. I attached another screenshot to my question to show you.

Comment: In your second screenshot, you are now not pinned to the SECOND button. They should all be pinned together consecutively TextView |-| Button |-| Button |-| Button

Comment: I didn't show them pinned together consecutively because that was what I had in the first screenshot. It doesn't matter whether I click-drag or do it the other way. I've tried both and both have the same gap as in the first screenshot.

Comment: In your first screenshot, there is no I-beam between the button and the textField, so they are not pinned.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there is or there isn't, regardless of how I did it including having the i beams on every one, it didn't work. I had tried this a bunch of times. Ultimately I fixed it by clicking the red button next to the controller in the left panel and removing everything and then having Xcode do it automatically with add missing constraints.

Comment: And what constraints are in the list after you did that? You should find out what constraints changed that made it work. Obviously you had one that was conflicting.